# Какие есть регулярные выражения в Си?

Tags: c, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте!

В переменной есть текст, в котором нужно найти информацию. Я планирую это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений. Столкнулся с проблемой при написании на Си. Заголовочный файл <regex.h> в MS VS 2010 отсутствует, есть файл <regex>, но работать с ним нельзя, так как он предназначен для C++, а я пишу на C(Си).

Подскажите, есть какая-то альтернативная библиотека/заголовочный файл или способ установки файла <regex.h> в VS?

Спасибо!

**PS**  Я так уперто пишу на Си, так как хочу перейти потом на objective-c. Или можно спокойно переходить на C++, так как это не повлечёт проблем при написании на objective-c? Или я ошибаюсь?

**ЗЗЫ** Уважаемый [@ХэшКод](/users/1/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), подскажите, пожалуйста, почему у меня пропала кнопка "добавить комментарий" - я не могу ответить на вопросы?

Comment: А просто запихнуть в проект regex.h почему не хотите?

Comment: @knes, а вы уверены, что там нет каких-то ещё сторонних которых тоже не будет в VS 2010?

Comment: >  так как это не повлечёт проблем при написании на objective-c  
  
Умение мыслить - вот то, что избавит проблем от написания на любом ЯП.  
Я сразу с Паскаля перешел.

Comment: @VioLet, ну как успехи? 
Есть свои приложения в AppStore?

Comment: Я под iOS не пишу, слава богу. Как успехи? Слышал может новости про бесплатные in-App покупки в iOS и OS X - отчасти и моя заслуга. Несколько библиотек + пишу части кода для других.

Comment: @VioLet, ты тот самый Алексей?

Comment: Нет, я ему немного помогал.

Comment: @VioLet, а что такого в написаниее приложений для iOS?
Или вы считаете написание под Android более выгодным?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК мне просто больше по душе системное программирование - копание в ОС, взаимодействие с ней на низком уровне, поиск дыр (как в защите, так и просто недокументированных функций) и их эсплуатация, написание фреймворков. А тратить 70% времени разработки на рисование GUI и иже с ним - это нравится меньше. Кушать, конечно, надо, поэтому и в iOS проектах приходится участвовать, но все же редко.

Comment: Хм, а с чем связано упертое нежелание гуглить? Поиск на developer.apple.com далеко не идеальный.

Comment: Вообще, вижу в предложенной теме два больших извращения: кодирование на С в VS и использование regexp в С.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Кроссплатформенный подход - это использовать [PRCE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F).

В стандарте ANSI C нет регулярных выражений. В GCC есть поддержка регулярных выражений: [Regular Expression Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) - это тот `regex.h`, который был упомянут. В Visual C++ при необходимости работы с регулярными выражениями подключают [CAtlRegExp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3zs4axe(v=vs.80).aspx) (код выносят в исходник на C++).

Comment: А какие есть для СИ решения?

Comment: Так @byte ответил -- pcre. Другие варианты -- POSIX regexp от gnu http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Ну, и поскольку MV VC -- это винды, то есть ещё вариант (доступен с 90х годов) -- использование объекта regexp (из JScript/VBScript). Требует наличия IE :)

Comment: @byte, @alexlz, перефразирую свой вопрос:   
Как мне установить эти регулярные выражения в MS VS 2010, что бы они работали с ЯП C(Си)?  
Спасибо.

Comment: Честно отвечу -- не знаю и MS VS у меня нет. Посмотрел, там на ftp в директории Contrib есть pcre-vsbuild.zip. Правда там для VS 2005  и VS 2008. Попробуйте скачать и построить библиотеку. Может поможет. POSIX регекспы по нынешним временам -- экзотика, а использование com-сервера на C++ -- достаточно извратный вариант.

Comment: @alexlz, То есть, писать программу которую я хочу(а я на 2/3 её написал) - это чисты изврат? Я не допонел просто.

Comment: Вообще извратом я назвал использование com-сервера (с интерфейсом-наследником IDispatch) на C.

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял вас.

Comment: Я писал про три варианта: 1 -- библиотека pcre, 2 -- библиотека posix-regexp, 3 -- использование com-объекта Regex. Извратом назвал третий, поскольку его использование на C++ -- это не две-три строки, а поболе, а уж использование com-объектов, наследников IDispatch (а не IUnknown) на C -- само по себе геморой.